# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SubGoods'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor, viewbag

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` I try this code in below for show fetched items from DB in `dropdownlist`, but I got this Error :

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'SubGoods'.
```

Action controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddSubGood()
    {
        ViewBag.SubGoods = new SelectList(db.MainGoods, "GoodID", "GoodTitle");
        return View();
    }
```

I try this :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FKMainGoodID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SubGoods",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SubGoods, "select main good")
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FKMainGoodID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("SubGoods", "select main good")
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I got same error.
Could any one tell me please what's the problem ?

Comment: everything looks fine.i guess you are trying add youur dropdownlist to different view. your dropdownlist must be under AddSubGood.cshtml

Comment: Thanks ,It's true , my Drop down is in  AddSubGood.cshtml  :/ @Zergling

Comment: i did same as you do , and its working for me. i used first view code block

Comment: :| , I don't know why every things didn't work for me :( , Thank you dear @Zergling

Comment: can u try it with ViewData please view :         @Html.DropDownList("SubGoods", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["SubGoods"], "select main good") , controller  :   ViewData["SubGoods"] = new SelectList(db.MainGoods, "GoodID", "GoodTitle");

Comment: Your code (First one) looks fine. It should work as long you have that code in `AddSubGood.cshtml`

Comment: I used it in `AddSubGood.cshtml` but it didn't work and gave me error . `FKMainGoodID` always gets `0` . @Shyju

Comment: Are you trying to bind the selected Dropdown option value to the FKMainGoodID property  ?

Comment: Yes , I want it  @Shyju

Comment: I try your code dear @Zergling but it gave me same error .

Comment: You are passing the wrong value in the DropDownList method. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to get the selected option value in the `FKMainGoodID` property of the posted model, use the string `"FKMainGoodID"` as the first parameter of the `DropDownList` helper method. This will generate the SELECT element with the name `FKMainGoodID` and model binding will work when you submit the form.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
      @Html.DropDownList("FKMainGoodID",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SubGoods,
                                                                      "select main good")
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you dear , your codes works fine like always . thanks a lot :)